# Align stacked divs so that the bottom div is lined up with the text in neighboring divs

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to HTML/CSS and I have a question about how to align divs that are stacked vertically.  I did some searching and couldn't find anyone else asking quite this same question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Stacking question." />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<style type="text/css">
    div.line {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 54px;
    }
    div.stacked {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='line'>
    The cat ran
  </div>
  <div class='stacked'>
    <div class='element'>
      under
    </div>
      <div class='element'>
        the
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='line'>
    table.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What you see here is a line of text where I've put the words in a few divs.  Please note, this may seem odd, but this precisely the way I want the divs arranged: if the ultimate answer to my query is "no - you can't do that" I am still happy because I am just trying to learn how all of this stuff works.

In the middle, I've stacked the divs containing the words "under" and "the."  What I want to know is this: is there a way that I can align the stacked divs so that the baseline of the div containing the word "under" is aligned with the baseline of the divs containing "ran" and "table?"

Comment: .stacked { vertical-align: middle;} this will align it to the baseline of the other two text

Answer (score 1):

```
.stacked {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align : middle;
}
```

This will make the stacked div to align to the baseline of the other two divs.

[image]